# Week Number in Teradata from Monday to Sunday

Tags: calendar, teradata, week-number

In Teradata `SYS_CALENDAR.CALENDAR` for year 2018 , the `WEEK_OF_YEAR` is starting from Sunday to Saturday. But I wanted `WEEK_OF_YEAR` to start from Monday to Sunday as `1`.

so `01-Jan-2018 to 07-Jan-2018` `WEEK_OF_YEAR`will be 1
:
:
and `31-Dec-2018` `WEEK_OF_YEAR`will be 53 
(Once year ended, should agian start from 1)
and `01-Jan-2019 to 06-Jan-2019` `WEEK_OF_YEAR`will be 1

Comment: Based on your rule the 1st sunday of a year is always in week 1?

Comment: @dnoeth the 1st Monday of a year is always in week 1

Comment: But then you might get a week 54 (leap year starting on Sunday, e.g. 2012)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will return your expected result, week from Sunday to Saturday and 1st Sunday of a year is always in week 1:

```
((DayNumber_Of_Year(calendar_date, 'compatible') + (6-DayNumber_Of_Week(calendar_date, 'iso'))) / 7) + 1
```

Use this once to create/update your own calendar. For repeated use you better wrap this calculation in a SQL UDF.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks